# Inserir elementos em um Array com Hooks e exibir em uma lista

Tags: react-native

Olá, pessoas. Sou novo no React-Native e ainda estou aprendendo alguns conceitos mais básicos.
Meu problema atual é o seguinte:
Eu quero fazer uma tela de itens recém pesquisados, de forma que quando o usuário clicar para digitar no TextInput, irá carregar abaixo a lista de itens que ele já pesquisou anteriormente.
Porém, estou tendo um erro `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop`

Já pesquisei bastante sobre o que pode ocasionar o erro, mas não consigo chegar em um denominador final.

```
function SearchList(){

    const [searchElement, setElement] = React.useState([]);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const valorDigitado = '';

    const addItem = (valor) => {
        setElement([ ...searchElement, {
            text: {valor},
        }])
    }

    return(
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                            <Feather name="chevron-left" size={25} color="#53565A" ></Feather> 
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.searchBar}>
                        <View
                        style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                            <Icon name="search" size={20} color="grey" />
                            <TouchableOpacity>
                                <TextInput 
                                style={styles.Search}
                                editable={true}
                                value={valorDigitado}
                                placeholder={"Pesquisar"}
                                returnKeyType={'search'}
                                onSubmitEditing={setElement(valorDigitado)}
                                >
                                </TextInput>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {/* <View>
                    <FlatList
                    data={searchElement}
                    renderItem={({item}) => {
                        return <Text>{item}</Text>
                    }}
                    />
                </View> */}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

Nessa linha você está chamando uma função (setElement) especificando um parâmetro, então não está passando ela por referência:

```
onSubmitEditing={setElement(valorDigitado)}
```

Nesses casos deve fazer assim:

```
onSubmitEditing={() => setElement(valorDigitado)}
```

Outra coisa, esse valorDigitado sempre vai ser igual a ''. Não entendi muito bem o que tentou. No value do TextInput colocamos uma variável de estado, com isso temos um componente controlado e podemos mudar o seu conteúdo entre as renderizações. Por exemplo:

```
const [texto,setTexto] = useState('')
<TextInput
    value={texto} //atribuo a variável de estado, componente controlado 
    onChangeText={texto => setTexto(texto)} //Defino o novo valor a cada digitação para que na próxima renderização mantenha o valor 
/ >
```

Observe que no caso acima, estou atribuindo a mesma variável(texto) que o evento devolve para a função setTexto, nesse caso posso passar a função como referência:

```
onChangeText={setTexto}
```